# Angular2.RC5: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of null

Tags: angular

I just upgraded from angular2.RC4 to angular2.RC5.   I am now getting

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of null

But I have no idea where to look to figure out how to fix it. The following is a screenshot of the error messages:

[image]

I would post code but, again, I don't even know where the offending code might be.  Any ideas on how to go about diagnosing/fixing this bug?

Comment: @torazaburo thanks for the hint.  am trying it now...

Comment: Could you share some code example? I had an issue with "http" after upgrading to rc5 maybe it's related too? https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10612#issuecomment-240048415

Comment: @Yves I had a problem with http too;  fixed it by putting {body:''} into the request params.  The problem referenced here was not related to http.  I finally fixed the bug, but I can't remember what I did to fix it (been thrashing around with all kinds of issues related to the RC5 release)

Comment: @brando do you use webpack with components/modules async load?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn on "Pause on caught exceptions" in devtools to catch it in the act.

[image]

This is likely to also stop on many uncaught exceptions in libraries. To deal with that, you can blackbox them.

Comment: thx for tip.  was able to find "No component factory found for HomeViewComponent" just before the promise error.  Not sure how to fix it, but it gives me somewhere to look!